# Nginx Browser Caching is not allowed here

Tags: performance, caching, browser, nginx, webserver

I tried to insert browser expire dates for all static types in nginx.
I copy this:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 365d;
}
```

before "server_tokens off;" at my:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

and get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:54
```

Anyone could help me?

---

Here the current working config!

---

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile       off;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;
#tcp_nodelay        on;


# output compression saves bandwidth
gzip  on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;

# make sure gzip does not lose large gzipped js or css files
# see http://blog.leetsoft.com/2007/07/25/nginx-gzip-ssl.html
gzip_buffers 16 8k;

# Disable gzip for certain browsers.
gzip_disable “MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)”;


server_tokens off;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

All based on a Ubuntu 12.04 VPS

Comment: You should read docs and understand that `location ...` is **not** _browser caching_ block.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `location` block is inside the `server` or `location` block.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location